# Python variable in SQL statement?

Tags: python, mysql, variables

I am trying to pass a variable to an SQL statement which I will eventually use in an iterator in order to process a list of key values and store in a CSV, however I am having trouble getting the variable into the statement?

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from MySQLdb import cursors
import csv

con = mdb.connect('172.16.7.50', 'root', 'abcd2014', 'templog')

tablename = 'pitemp'

with con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT temp, time FROM %s", (tablename,))

fid = open('new.csv','w')

writer = csv.writer(fid, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row
writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())

print 'finished!'
```

I have tried a selection of different bracket combinations as found on stack overflow but they all result in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tom/PycharmProjects/TomsSQL2CSV/sql2csv.py", line 11, in <module>
cursor.execute("SELECT temp, time FROM %s", (vari,))
File "/home/tom/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line    205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/home/tom/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the  right syntax to use near ''pitemp'' at line 1")
```

Comment: _cursor.execute("SELECT temp, time FROM %s", (tablename,))_ Is that an extra comma after tablename ?

Comment: @Stiffo Yes, because that's a tuple.

Comment: If it's a tuple, that will result in extra ' ' characters, resulting in a broken SQL statement, wont it?

Comment: It looks like extra '' are being added in the error... Any ideas?

Comment: @Stiffo: `"SELECT temp, time FROM %s"` and `(tablename,)` are two different parameters to `execute()`, and that method *doesn't* apply the `%` operator between the two of them. `execute()` takes a tuple even if there's only one value to substitute. Actually `"SELECT temp, time FROM %s" % (tablename,)` wouldn't have parentheses in the result, because the `%` operator treats tuples specially, but it's not relevant either way :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Nice one! That works. So the % operator you added between the two parameters, what does that do in a nutshell?

cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s" % (vari, vari2,))

Comment: Look at Python documentation for how to use the `%` operator, it works along similar principles to the `str.format()` function. However, don't get into the *general habit* of constructing SQL statements using string operations. Down that road lie copious opportunities to create SQL injection vulnerabilities, and others have travelled it before you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You should be using '?' for parameter bindings in your sql string not
python format specifiers (you are after all writing sql here not
python).

```
cursor.execute("SELECT temp, time FROM ?", (tablename,))
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use the table name as a parameter?

Comment: Everywhere I have read says that both ? %s are usable depending on what driver I use?

Comment: You're using SQL parameters, not Python parameters, if you use %s MySQL will read it like that and ignore your parameter, the way to tell MySQL that you want to put a parameter there is with '?'.

You can use %s for Python parameters but no for SQL parameters

Comment: Ok, well the ? still doesn't work. 

    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: try this:
`cursor.execute("SELECT temp, time FROM ?", [tablename])`

Comment: @tomstephens89 was its useful for you?  Tell me please so then I'll can update the answer for future people with the same doubt.